# How to Navigate without the navigation prop with createSwitchNavigator

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, redux-saga

Im using react-native with react-navigation already when i decided to use redux and redux-saga.
My problem is i dont know how to navigate inside reducer or saga files.
I found this [link on how to navigate without navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html) but the example is different from my entry file (index.js) and top-level navigator (src/App.js, not sure if this is top-level navigator).

index.js (entry)

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import store from './src/store';
import App from './src/App';

class Entry extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
  }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testApp', () => Entry);
```

src/App.js

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import HomeContainer from './containers/HomeContainer';
import SplashContainer from "./containers/SplashContainer";
import LoginContainer from "./containers/LoginContainer";

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeContainer,
  }
);

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: LoginContainer,
  }
);

export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Splash: SplashContainer,
    Dashboard: HomeStack,
    Login: LoginStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash"
  }
);
```

package.json

```
"react-native": "0.55.4",
"react-navigation": "^2.1.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
```

Comment: Where is your saga & reducer?

Comment: Hi, already solved it. is it ok if i put navigate in my reducer? let's say when my login is success it will navigate to home. @digit

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding ref in my src/App.js. It turns out [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html) is already the answer, i just got confused because of different example or approach.

index.js (entry)

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <App ref={navigatorRef => {
    navigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
  }}/>
</Provider>
```

Comment: How to navigate using that ref?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to navigate inside of a saga file even though your question doesn't show a saga file.

You can pass the navigation object in the action that your saga is listening for, and then use it like normal in that file.

I'm using this to navigate after a successful sign up action. Here's an example.

In your component:

```
class SignUpForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }
...
  dispatchSignUp() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const { signUp, navigation } = this.props;

    signUp(email, password, navigation);
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <Button onPress={() => this.dispatchSignUp()} />
    ...
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  signUp: (email, password, navigation) => dispatch(signUpAction(email, password, navigation)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUpForm);
```

your action:

```
const signUp = (email, password, navigation) => ({
  type: 'SIGN_UP',
  email,
  password,
  navigation,
});

export default signUp;
```

your saga:

```
import { takeLatest, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { createUser } from '../services/index';

export function* signUpWorker(action) {
  try {
    const { email, password, navigation } = action;
    const payload = { email, password };
    const data = yield call(createUser, payload);

    yield put({ type: 'SIGN_UP_SUCCESS', data });

    navigation.navigate('Main');
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: 'SIGN_UP_ERROR', error });
  }
}

export default function* signUpWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest('SIGN_UP', signUpWorker);
}
```

`navigation.navigate('Main')` is the important part. Hope there wasn't too much junk in the way.

Cheers.